# How can I create a file with some text in it using bash script

Tags: bash

I write a  bash script in my .sh which takes class name as its argument.
When this script is run, it creates a directory named `class` in the same space as that of the the script.

Then, it creates a PHP file with the same class name received from the argument inside the `class` directory. But if there is a same file already, exit the program instead.

Problem: It is working on Microsoft's windows but I need to work it also on Gnu/Linux

This is my `.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_PATH="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
mkdir -p $CURRENT_PATH/class
cd $CURRENT_PATH/class
if [ -f "$@.php" ];
then
   exit 1
else
   echo "class $@
{
}" > $@.php
fi
```

Comment: Please define "work": what is different between when it works and when it doesn't? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: And define not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problems I see are the lack of quotes, so it will go wrong if there are spaces in the directory/file names.

```
#!/bin/bash

current_path="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
mkdir -p "$current_path/class"
cd "$current_path/class"
if [ -f "$1.php" ];
then
   exit 1
else
   echo "class $1
{
}" > "$1.php"
fi
```

There is also a problem of using `"$@"`, is that what you intended. Did you mean `"$*"`?

and variable names should be lower-case. I don't see how this will cause a problem here, but is a bug waiting to happen.

Running `shellcheck` would have found most of these errors.

Comment: yup, it`s working now. changing the @ into 1 and also i forgot to change my line endings to unix.